# Wireshark -Protocol Hierarchy Omitting large amount of subprotocol traffic

Tags: wireshark, statistics

[image]

Based on responses, I've repositioned this question to ask why the subprotocols under my TCP header are not accounting for the sum of packet transfer. (I.E TCP= 97.1%, remainder of packet content not listed in subvariants/subprotocols)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each hierarchical item contains subitems that should sum up to the same amount - however, there's no *Other* and that figure is omitted.

For instance, *Internet Protocol version 4* contains (is the sum of) *User Datagram Protocol*, *Transmission Control Protocol*, *Internet Group Management Protcol*, *Internet Control Message Protocol*, and (omitted) *Other*.

*Transmission Control Protocol* just lists some subvariants that don't sum up nicely (there's a rather large *Other*).

Comment: Hi Zac, Originally I had actually posted this thread as "Wireshark Protocol Hierarchy omitting large amount of packet data". So this would make sense, I was wondering why my subprotocols were not adding to account for the Protocol's traffic.

 What exactly is going on here, is it a matter of my wireshark preferences omitting this 'other' data or something else.
If it helps, and not to be conspiratorial, I've expressed concern of being compromised which is part my reason for delving into packet analysis and other areas of device security.

Comment: If needed I can transfer this question to another appropriate stack-exchange

Comment: Wireshark only displays common protocols and variants. I can see no easy way to customize the display aside from working on the source code (which should be addressed elsewhere)... However, Wireshark isn't a very good tool for statistical monitoring - perhaps you should look into Netflow or sFlow tools instead.

Comment: Would questions posed towards malware activity be valid here? From my understanding Wireshark doesn't have the dissectors to analyze the remaining ~70% subprotocol traffic being generated in this capture?

Comment: Wireshark can very well analyze packets *that you have defined* (compare microscope) - dissecting mass traffic into known and unknown flows should be done with statistically working tools. Malware activity is above the transport layer, so it's off-topic here. Depending on your goals, it might be on-topic on [sf] - but please do check their scope before posting.

Comment: Deleted comment: Will refer to netflow or sFlow to understand this

Comment: Wireshark not dissecting data doesn't mean that's not possible. Its statistics are just a rough overview, no flow level analysis. If you know what you're looking for you can filter traffic appropriately, but for quantitative analysis Wireshark isn't the proper tool.